# Instruction for installing rc to LEGO unimog

Tags: technic

I'm searching for an instruction to install a remote control to my LEGO unimog.

There are a log of youtube videos showing completed unimogs but I can't find any instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this utoob](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBo3al7sk5I) video as the first hit for a [search using "install pf lego unimog"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=install%20pf%20in%20lego%20unimog) and also this [thread on EuroBricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=57543&st=150) Which recommends a [different video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQIBRyDFwcY). So instructions are definitely out there.

I think you'd be better off trying it yourself. Don't be intimidated by the size or complexity of the unimog, have a go. Worst case you'll have to reassemble it using the TLG instructions and then try some of the online instructions.